# Relationship between vectors of a triangle and dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

So I have to make this exercise:

$\vec u + \vec v + \vec w  = 0$ I also know that $||\vec u|| = \frac{3}{2}, ||\vec v|| = \frac{1}{2}, ||\vec w||=2$. Now take:

$$\vec u \cdot \vec v + \vec v \cdot \vec w + \vec w \cdot \vec u  $$

So, am I forgetting some identity or technique? I imagine that since $\vec u + \vec v + \vec w  = 0$ they form a triangle, but I don't know how to proceed. I tough of using cosine law or something since I have the sides of the triangle, but is there a easier way to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$\left(\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w}\right)=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}+\vec{w}\cdot\vec{w}+2\left[\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}+\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u}\right]$

Comment: Could you please tell the answer? Mine is -2 but in the book it says it's -13/4. Thanks!

Comment: I did $0 = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + 2  + 2\left[\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}+\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u}\right]
 
$

Comment: $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=\left\Vert u\right\Vert ^{2}=\frac{9}{4}$ etcetera. You forg0t squaring it. The answer in the book is okay.

Comment: tahk you SO MUCH! :)